# int array vs individual ints?

Tags: java, optimization

I am currently representing [128-bit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/128-bit) integers in [J2ME](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Platform%2C_Micro_Edition) (which need to be created tens of millions of times) with objects holding a `new int[4]`. Is this reasonably less efficient than simply using 4 individual variables?

Comment: j2me is still a thing? what platform are you running it on?

Comment: I wouldn't really say it's 'still a thing', nonetheless right now I'm running it in the Sun Emulator, but my target is the Nokia C2-01

Answer (score 4):

If you have "tens of millions" of small arrays, then you have tens of millions of the array object overhead.

A `int[4]` would take a reference value (4 bytes), and an array (16 bytes overhead), so 10 million values would use 200 Mb *extra* space. If you run Java with lots of memory, so compressed OOPS cannot be used, the extra space use is higher.

To store a 128-bit value, I would recommend using two `long` fields.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't use two longs because emulating certain arithmetic requires that I have a type that is larger than the one I'm using (so I can pick off the high portion). So if I do this I'll need to split it into 4 ints.

Comment: @Faissaloo Splitting a `long` into 2 `int` is easy, as is combining them back, but sure, if you prefer 4 fields instead of 2 for the *storage* of the value, then go ahead. Just remember, that how you store the value, and how you calculate on the value, don't have to be the same thing. But, either way works.

Comment: Yeah it's more so just been the case that most of the calculations require ints so I don't want the overhead of breaking it out every time.